# Laravel 6 All api gives 401 unauthorized

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 6.18.10 as Backend (APIs) and Front-end core Vue.js

In my local machine with virtual domain all is working fine. but in production server it is not working.

in production server, normal laravel login is working also normal API login is also working but

other apis is not working.

in `api.php` I found that if I remove `auth:api` then it is not getting `Auth:user()` object. (see below code)

`Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api','cors'] ], function(){`

I don't know why it happened. because normal Login is working , I check it with Postman and login is working but other api url getting `404` json response `{"message":"Unauthenticated."}`

Please Help

```
I try all below thing :
1) composer update
2) rollback all database and re migrate and again install passport
3) change passport keys
```

Answer (score 0):

Tarun, `auth:api` is a guard used to authenticate the user. So if you are testing from postman, then 401 unauthorized is a valid response for api's that require authentication to proceed further.

To continue testing with postman, I came across a [Laravel Authorisation in Postman](https://medium.com/@joelbutcher/laravel-authorisation-in-postman-c3f76bedc0fc) & [API Workflow with Postman](https://www.sitepoint.com/master-api-workflow-postman/). You can go though these documents for better understanding of postman.

Apart from that, you can read [Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport) or [Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/sanctum) if you are planning to use API.

Comment: I think your answer is not related to the question, the Passport and Sanctum work in different way the question is about basic auth:api